# readonly DependencyProperty derived from other DependencyProperty

Tags: wpf, data-binding, dependency-properties

My object has one true property `VideoDimension` and one property `VideoRatio` which is basically a "reduced" version of the former.
I am looking for a way to connect the two in the most elegant way possible.

```cs
public static readonly DependencyProperty VideoDimensionProperty = 
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        nameof(VideoDimension), 
        typeof(Point), 
        typeof(MyControl), 
        new PropertyMetadata(new Point(0, 0))
    );
public Point VideoDimension
{
    get { return (Point)GetValue(VideoDimensionProperty); }
    set { SetValue(VideoDimensionProperty, value); }
}


public static readonly DependencyProperty VideoRatioProperty = 
    MysteryFunction(VideoDimensionProperty, (value) =>
        {
            Point point = (Point)value;
            return point.X / point.Y;
        });
public double VideoRatio
{
    get { return (double)GetValue(VideoRatioProperty); }
}
```

What could this `MysteryFunction` above be?
I would like to have `VideoRatio` calculated in a lazy fashion.

The working workarounds I found so far are:

- Make `VideoRatioProperty` its own `DependencyProperty`, and manually update it when `VideoDimension` is Changed. This is not ideal because:

  - `VideoRatioProperty` may be calculated for nothing, if no one is listening to it.
  - It creates a second source of truth. It makes one able to modify `VideoRatio` and not `VideoDimension`. This can be alleviated using `RegisterReadOnly` to protect it from `public` callers, but the owner object can still modify it.
- Only use `VideoRatio` as a lightweight getter that would compute the value on the fly. But then it becomes hard to make other elements bind to it, since they should listen to the `VideoDimensionProperty` notifier, but take the value from `VideoRatio`. This is too much to know from an external caller.
- Dont use `VideoRatio` at all, but make the callers listen to `VideoDimension` with a binding `Converter` that would calculate the ratio. This is also too much to know from an external caller, and this is definitely not scalable.

Answer (score 1):

> *"Calculated for nothing, if no one is listening to it"*

The source object shouldn't care if anyone "listens" to it. It should update its state regardless so this isn't an issue.

> *"But then it becomes hard to make other elements bind to it..."*

You could implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in your class and raise the `PropertyChanged` event for the `VideoDimension` whenever you want to notify the subscribers.

> "But the owner object can still modify it"

Not only it can - it should. That's its responsibility. Whether it sets a read-only dependency property explicitly using the key or raise a `PropertyChanged` event for a read-only CLR property is just a matter of taste.

You shouldn't force the external callers to use a converter to get the value. The other two options are perfectly fine and should be seen as solutions rather than workarounds.

Answer (score 1):

With properties it can be done like this, using PropertyChangedCallback and a readonly VideoRatio property:

```
public Point VideoDimension
{
    get { return (Point)GetValue(VideoDimensionProperty); }
    set { SetValue(VideoDimensionProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty VideoDimensionProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        nameof(VideoDimension), 
        typeof(Point), 
        typeof(MainWindow), 
        new PropertyMetadata(new Point(0,0), VideoDimensionChangedCallback));

private static void VideoDimensionChangedCallback(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Point p = (Point)e.NewValue;
    d.SetValue(VideoRatioPropertyKey, p.X / p.Y);
}

public double VideoRatio
{
    get { return (double)GetValue(VideoRatioProperty); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty VideoRatioProperty = VideoRatioPropertyKey.DependencyProperty;

private static readonly DependencyPropertyKey VideoRatioPropertyKey =
    DependencyProperty.RegisterReadOnly(
        nameof(VideoRatio), 
        typeof(double), 
        typeof(MainWindow), 
        new PropertyMetadata(0));
```

Comment: Thanks. Also `SetValue(VideoRatioPropertyKey, ...)` should be used to get autorisation to modify the entry.